# Use expand in actionIndex

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have override actionIndex() method. Now i want to use expand in param. My code is here

```
  public function actions() {
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['index']);
    unset($actions['create']);
    unset($actions['update']);
    unset($actions['delete']);
    return $actions;
}



public function actionIndex() {
 $query = $this->model::find();
 $query->someCondition()->all();
  return $query
 }
```

My Model is

```
 public function fields() {
    return [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];
}

public function extraFields() {
     return ['status'];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How i get data from extra field when i override actionIndex

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-resources#fields